# Android webkit.WebView and HTML5

Tags: android, html, webkit, webview, websocket

is there any list which HTML5 features the WebView supports and which not? I am interested mainly in:

1) localStorage/sessionStorage

2) offline manifest

3) web sockets

4) web workers

Prior there was lack of those features (http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg60143.html), but in Android 2.1, first two should be supported, but I am not sure about 3 and 4. Is there any list of supported features or we have to test it on our own?

Thanks a lot
BR
STeN

Comment: Hi, so far it looks to me that only localStorage is supported and that's also quite strange, that the Google documentation is pretty silent and unkindly about the HTML5 features support in such a important component for hybrid applications...

Comment: Hi STeN, I want to follow up on your initial question.... since it's now half a year later, and we're at Android 2.3 (on some devices) - did you find out anything more on which html5 features are actually supported by the WebView? Really still only the localStorage? Thanks for an update!

Comment: Hi, I have quite a bad experience with the Android OS browser, whatever version it is. Google supports is bad - check here http://bit.ly/fVcJJX... It has buggy <audio> and <video> elements and in general the mobile browser is much worse then iOS Safari + the rendering on Android devices is slower (especially on cheaper devices). Since then I am going with the native solution only. I wanted to save time by having multiplatform code, but this is not true - might be for simple application... but when it goes complicated use better Java/Objective-C.

Comment: I btw used also Sencha Touch framework. It works well on iPhone/iPad, worse on Android and really bad on Blackberry, but is really difficult for beginner and it cannot be compared to Android API or iOS Cocoa Touch... I develop the apps for the 7 months on this framework and if not really requested by customer I will always go with native - this is my experience, but I am open ti discuss.

Answer (score 3):

Mobile browser info is actually now included on caniuse.com, for your list see:

http://caniuse.com/#agents=mobile&feat=namevalue-storage,offline-apps,websockets,webworkers

Or for everything:
http://caniuse.com/#agents=mobile

Answer (score 1):

For complete HTML5, CSS3 features supported by Android browser, see

- [http://html5test.com](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/android23/android32/android40.html)
- http://mobilehtml5.org/

Answer (score 0):

The right answer ought to be caniuse.com which is currently the best site for non-mobile browser info. From what I've found there is no other site which has this sort of information. I would encourage you to encourage the maintainer of caniuse.com to add mobile browser information. You can do that by posting here:

http://a.deveria.com/?p=82#comments

Comment: Hi, it would be great, if there will be some page focusing on mobile web browsers for Symbian,Android, iPhone and Blackberry and also page focusing on wrapper components on those mobile phones like UIWebView on iPhone, webkit.WebView on Android, QWebView on Symbian Qt and BrowserField2 on Blackberry. I am mobile phone developer, who is doing also hybrid native/HTML5 applications and knowing the level of mobile support for HTML5, CSS3 features will help me a lot! I am open to help creator of such a page.
BR