# Does android webview browsers support html5 features?

Tags: android, html, webview

I have HTML5 based web application i want it to integrate with WebView ,So does android webview browsers support html5 features?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930045/android-webkit-webview-and-html5

Answer (score 54, accepted):

A `WebView` supports them, **but you have to turn them on**. I use the following code which turns on every features which are available. This is necessary because Application Caches for example are not supported on All Android-Versions:

```
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();

    ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ws.setAllowFileAccess(true);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "Enabling HTML5-Features");
            Method m1 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setDomStorageEnabled", new Class[]{Boolean.TYPE});
            m1.invoke(ws, Boolean.TRUE);

            Method m2 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setDatabaseEnabled", new Class[]{Boolean.TYPE});
            m2.invoke(ws, Boolean.TRUE);

            Method m3 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setDatabasePath", new Class[]{String.class});
            m3.invoke(ws, "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/");

            Method m4 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setAppCacheMaxSize", new Class[]{Long.TYPE});
            m4.invoke(ws, 1024*1024*8);

            Method m5 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setAppCachePath", new Class[]{String.class});
            m5.invoke(ws, "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/cache/");

            Method m6 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setAppCacheEnabled", new Class[]{Boolean.TYPE});
            m6.invoke(ws, Boolean.TRUE);

            Log.d(TAG, "Enabled HTML5-Features");
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Reflection fail", e);
        }
        catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Reflection fail", e);
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Reflection fail", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: My AndroidStudio keeps telling me not to hardcode `/data`. How can I replace the two occurrences?

Comment: hi @Bowi use context.getFilesDir().getPath()

Comment: As of Android P, this will almost certainly not work if it did before - [see here](https://developer.android.com/preview/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces)

Comment: where is that /data location exactly?

Comment: I was looking for the reason why my angular 9 was not starting as expected. You saved me! Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

On your android browser open this link : http://html5test.com it will give you all the information that you need : Parsing rules , Canvas ,video,Audio,elements,forms,webapp...

Comment: thanks @moujib this is awesome that will help me in desktop browsers too

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @theomega I used the following way to enable using light touches to make a selection and activate mouseovers.

```
try {
    WebSettings.class.getMethod("setLightTouchEnabled", new Class[]{Boolean.TYPE});
} catch (SecurityException e) {         
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {         
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify which features you're looking for exactly,
but Android (and iOS) use Webkit. So yes.

Comment: actually i m looking drag and drop ,video,canvas features like that s

Comment: Actually the default Android browser has some troubles with a support of the features of HTML5. Maybe this [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/retomeier/html5-or-android-for-mobile-development) will helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Use JavaScript bridge in Android to integrate with WebView:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(JavaScriptShareInterface(::exampleFunction))
    }
    private fun exampleFunction(s: String) {
      // do something when it is called
    }
}

class JavaScriptShareInterface(
    private val exampleCallback: (string: String) -> Unit,
) {
     // You can call this in webpage code
    @JavascriptInterface
    fun doExample(string: String?) {
        exampleCallback.invoke(string)
    }

}
```