# Swipe to navigate and stop audio

Tags: android, iphone, html, jquery-mobile

I want to build an app using jQuery-Mobile which every single page contains an image and autoplay audio.
when the first page is swiped to the next page, the first page's audio stops playing and the second page's starts playing.
Can anyone help me how to do it or inform me a plugin.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show your codes / what have you tried ?

Comment: I have tried jquery.swipegallery but it is working fine with the images but a problem with the audio

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery Mobile `pagehide` or `pagebeforehide` events to stop audio files.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforehide', function () {
  $(this).find('audio').each(function () {
    $(this)[0].pause();
  });
});
```

Comment: No idea whats going on, but on Android 4.1 i have to pause the audio *before* pagebeforehide happens or it will just continue playing.

Comment: @jgillich what do you mean before `pagebeforehide`? Pause audio manually or programmatically?

Comment: Ya thats cool.. but when the first page is swiped, the whole page's audio stops. What I want is to stop the first page and play the next page. What shall I do? Thanks

Comment: The code above stops audio on the current/active page. Can you post some relevant code? @TeamirGassese

Comment: `<script>
 $(document).on('pagebeforehide', function () {
  $(this).find('audio').each(function () {
  $(this)[0].pause();
 });
 });
</script> `
<br/>
`<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" class="ui-page"> 
        Content Here
 </div>
 <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" class="ui-page"> 
        Content Here
 </div>`

Comment: @Omar Programmatically, I don't use controls. But your code works fine on any desktop browser, just not on a Android 4.1 device, probably yet another bug of the Android WebView.

Comment: I also tried to call pause() on the element directly; the element is found and pause() caused no errors, but it just continued playing. Just wanted to note this in case someone else stumbles over this issue.

Comment: @jgillich then maybe Android WebView doesn't support `audio` features. It should support HTML5, weird. I will look it up.

Comment: @jgillich http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599739/does-android-webview-browsers-support-html5-features

Comment: `audio` works fine. I have tried two things to stop audio when the user navigates away:
1. Your code from above. When I click a button linking to another page, pause() executes, page changes but audio keeps playing.
2. Bind a function to a button that calls pause() *before* calling $.mobile.changePage(). This does actually work, audio pauses and page change happens.

Comment: @jgillich so `pagehide` or `pagebeforehide` events dont stop audio?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33714/discussion-between-omar-and-jgillich)

Comment: hi @omar, if you're interested in HTML5 consulting for a mobile app for iOS devices, could you please email me at info at panabee dot com? thanks.

Comment: Hi @Crashalot thanks for your offer. We are actually discussing Android WebView capabilities. If you have any addition, please feel free :)