# List of Html5 features supported in Android2.1 and 2.2

Tags: android-webview

Can any one tell what are all the Html5 features supported in Android2.1 and 2.2 application.
I need to use html5 into my android application using Webview. But i don't know what are the features supported in Android 2.1 and 2.2.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check these features at runtime (and possibly turn them on yourself), through the following code copied from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10599794/2611470):

```
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();

    ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ws.setAllowFileAccess(true);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "Enabling HTML5-Features");
            Method m1 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setDomStorageEnabled", new Class[]{Boolean.TYPE});
            m1.invoke(ws, Boolean.TRUE);

            Method m2 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setDatabaseEnabled", new Class[]{Boolean.TYPE});
            m2.invoke(ws, Boolean.TRUE);

            Method m3 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setDatabasePath", new Class[]{String.class});
            m3.invoke(ws, "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/");

            Method m4 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setAppCacheMaxSize", new Class[]{Long.TYPE});
            m4.invoke(ws, 1024*1024*8);

            Method m5 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setAppCachePath", new Class[]{String.class});
            m5.invoke(ws, "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/cache/");

            Method m6 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setAppCacheEnabled", new Class[]{Boolean.TYPE});
            m6.invoke(ws, Boolean.TRUE);

            Log.d(TAG, "Enabled HTML5-Features");
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Reflection fail", e);
        }
        catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Reflection fail", e);
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Reflection fail", e);
        }
    }
```