# Issues in loading Angular JS website in Android Webview

Tags: android, angularjs, webview, android-webview

Hi EveryOne I am trying to load [GTV](http://gtvqa.com/#!/) into Android WebView.It loads in Mobile browser quite well but not in webview.
Here is my Code.

```
  WebView theWebPage  = new WebView(this);
    theWebPage.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    theWebPage.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(theWebPage);
    WebViewClient client = new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    };
    theWebPage.setWebViewClient(client);
```

//        client.onPageStarted(theWebPage);

```
    theWebPage.loadUrl("http://gtvqa.com/#!/");
```

Comment: Have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging.html

Comment: What is the problem? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AngularJS requires an HTML5-compliant browser and I don't think that the default Android WebView is. Unless you are the developer of that website and can add modernizer to the page to attempt to account for older, non-compliant browsers, you might not be able to solve this.

Comment: Ofcource I can add.By mordenizer do you mean modernizer.js ?  I'll add and see.

Comment: I found another way to enable HTML5 in [Enable HTML5 in WebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599739/does-android-webview-browsers-support-html5-features). By The way you identified the real problem.Thanks @mbielski

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant (modernizer.js) but glad you found a better solution to the problem.

Comment: I was looking for the reason why my angular 9 was not starting as expected. You saved me! Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

I found this function helpful

```
this.webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When posting code as solutions, it is helpful to explain how your code solves OP's problem :)

Comment: I had the same issue. I tried to wrap a web application based on AngularJs  with webView in android studio. When I tried to log in nothing happened. After putting this line of code the application worked like magic within webView :)

Comment: This solved my issues.

Answer (score 1):

By default android webview doesn't support HTML5 features, therefore sometimes there are issues with a AngularJS site.

You have to enable the HTML5 in webview to solve that issue.

Follow this method, you will be fine.

```
private void initWebView(View view) {
    webView=findViewById(R.id.webView);
    loadWebViewDatafinal(webView, webURL);
}

private void loadWebViewDatafinal(WebView wv, String url) {
        WebSettings ws=wv.getSettings();

        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ws.setAllowFileAccess(true);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
            try {
                Log.e("WEB_VIEW_JS", "Enabling HTML5-Features");
                Method m1=WebSettings.class.getMethod("setDomStorageEnabled", new Class[]{Boolean.TYPE});
                m1.invoke(ws, Boolean.TRUE);

                Method m2=WebSettings.class.getMethod("setDatabaseEnabled", new Class[]{Boolean.TYPE});
                m2.invoke(ws, Boolean.TRUE);

                Method m3=WebSettings.class.getMethod("setDatabasePath", new Class[]{String.class});
                m3.invoke(ws, "/data/data/" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/databases/");

                Method m4=WebSettings.class.getMethod("setAppCacheMaxSize", new Class[]{Long.TYPE});
                m4.invoke(ws, 1024 * 1024 * 8);

                Method m5=WebSettings.class.getMethod("setAppCachePath", new Class[]{String.class});
                m5.invoke(ws, "/data/data/" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/cache/");

                Method m6=WebSettings.class.getMethod("setAppCacheEnabled", new Class[]{Boolean.TYPE});
                m6.invoke(ws, Boolean.TRUE);

                Log.e("WEB_VIEW_JS", "Enabled HTML5-Features");
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                Log.e("WEB_VIEW_JS", "Reflection fail", e);
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                Log.e("WEB_VIEW_JS", "Reflection fail", e);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                Log.e("WEB_VIEW_JS", "Reflection fail", e);
            }
        }

        wv.loadUrl(url);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just in case someone is wondering wants a c# answer,

```
webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
```

This one line saved my life.

Comment: Add explanation to your code and format it correctly.

Comment: My android webview was unable to load an angular website. After trying a lot of unsuccessful fixes,
adding this line to my initialized webview worked and the website loaded perfectly:
`webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;`