# Android webview not rendering CSS and angular

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, webview, android-webview

I am trying to load a URL in to android native webview, but it does not render `CSS` and `Angular`

**CODE:**

```
    WebView wvFAQs = (WebView) mFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.wvUrls);

    Map<String, String> headersMap = new HashMap<>();
    headersMap.put(ApiConstants.AUTHORIZATION, BuildConfig.SS_API_AUTH);
    wvFAQs.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    wvFAQs.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wvFAQs.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
    wvFAQs.loadUrl(mUrl,headersMap);
```

**ERRORS:**

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined",
>
> "Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined",
>
> "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",

but this URL works fine in mobile browsers (chrome & default android browser).

when i googled this issue, i came to know that i need to enable html5 support feature in webiew, here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599739/does-android-webview-browsers-support-html5-features), but still not working.

Can anyone tell me what might be the issue? is there any issue with the URL or webview?

Answer (score 0):

I use this Java code to load the webview:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); //try js alert
    view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); // adding js alert support
}

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && view.canGoBack()) {
        view.goBack(); //method goback()
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

What I can say is if that you use Jquery you need to add it to your assets because external links like from cdn like:

```
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
```

would not load.

Comment: my URL was public, not local. Well i fixed my issue, using android custom tabs. :)