# I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "ERROR" angular 5 error when called in web view

Tags: android, angular, angular5, android-webview

I have created a website in angular 5 which my client currently want to call using android webview.

when we call the same in web view, we get an error - **I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "ERROR"** .

Do i need to make any changes in the module file?

Thank in advance.

Comment: don't treat WebView as full-functional web browser. Don't expect that everything will work same as in a Web Browser there.

Comment: Hi @VladyslavMatviienko, thanks for the reply, I am not even able to load the first page of the website. It gives me below error.

I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "ERROR", source: main.7badac4449598ab7aa88.bundle.js (1)

[INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "ERROR", source: main.7badac4449598ab7aa88.bundle.js (1)

[INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Property '__zone_symbol__then' of object [object Promise] is not a function", source: polyfills.42ec37fb3fd9269560ec.bundle.js (1)

Comment: As I said, don't expect it to work because it likely won't work

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to add html5 support to your webview. pls check how to add html5 support.

[Does android webview browsers support html5 features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599739/does-android-webview-browsers-support-html5-features)