# Website on API 16 looks bad versus newer API

Tags: android, html, api, webview

I'm developing an android app with a webview. On API 21 Lollipop, the website is properly centered and looks good. This is the first picture. But on API 16 Jelly Bean, the text is off-center. This is the second picture. I noticed that this also happens in the browser too, so maybe this is an html problem? Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Sorry that the pictures are so big, these are screenshots straight from android.

[image: on API 21] [image: on API 16]

Comment: You do realize that API 16 is using the WebKit include in the OS while API 21 is probably on a recent release of Chrome. See: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview

Comment: No, I never knew that. Is there a way for me to work around it?

Comment: Sorry I can't offer better advice than "you'll have to figure out why the layout isn't what you would expect". Anyone dealing with the Android WebView had to deal with the various quirks from the beginning (http://stackoverflow.com/q/3930045/295004). Android L makes it a bit easier (http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2016/02/webview_stats.html) but if you search around both here and elsewhere you'll see trials and tribulations (looking at you Samsung).

Comment: Can you help point me in the right direction? I'm not familiar with html or webviews internally so I'm not sure where to start. It could be html, but I'm not sure what tags to touch.

Comment: Either restrict the minSDK to one which it will appear acceptable, or reach out to the data source to see if another feed is available. If you don't have control over the content there isn't much you can do, at least not without good html/css/javascript knowledge as you would need to alter the data as you load it in and of course the source could break it at any time.

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks Morrison. The help was invaluable

Comment: By the way, if you wanted to post your comments as an answer, I'll up vote and select it. Otherwise, I'll put it up myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you see such a difference between older Android devices and Lollipop is that until KitKat Android was using its own version of WebKit and with Lollipop is updatable via the Google Play Store.

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview

Unfortunately anyone dealing with the Android WebView had to deal with the various quirks from the beginning ([Android webkit.WebView and HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3930045/295004)).

Android L makes it a bit easier (http://quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2016/02/webview_stats.html) but if you search around both here and elsewhere you'll see trials and tribulations (looking at you Samsung).

The easiest advice is to either restrict the minSDK to one which it will appear acceptable, or reach out to the data source to see if another feed is available. If you don't have control over the content there isn't much you can do, at least not without good html/css/javascript knowledge as you would need to alter the data as you load it in and of course the source could break it at any time.

**Alternate Path**

If supporting older versions of Android is a absolute requirement. You could look into including your own WebView with the Crosswalk project (https://crosswalk-project.org/) at the cost of additional build, development, and support complexity.